# Missing hive execution jar 3.1.2

Tags: hive, jar

Hi I am trying to run the following command while installing hive 3.1.2

`bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`

When I run this it tells me "`Missing Hive Execution Jar: home/<user>/hive/lib/hive-exec-*.jar`". I looked into my `/hive/lib directory` and it contains the  `hive-exec-3.1.2.jar`. I'm running a 32-bit Ubuntu VM, that has Hadoop already installed on it and working. Java is up to date if that helps too, thanks for the help. First, I unpacked my apache hive tar file, moved it to my home directory changed it to just hive, then I set the `export HIVE_HOME= “home/<user>/hive”
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin`. Next, I made the following change to core-site.xml in hadoop,

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.firepower.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.firepower.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Than I made a tmp directory and a user directory in hdfs with write privileges. However when I did this it was giving me error about a disabled stack guard, and that i should run execstac -c , and WARN util.NativeCodeLoder: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platfor... using builtin-java classes. But i was still able to create the dirs. Than after that I tried to initalize the derby databse with the schematool.

Comment: Please edit your question to include every step from following the Hive site to download and extract, configuring, then running that command